# How can I schedule hourly request to a server and store data on my own server to access from iOS app?

Tags: ios, server-side

I have very little server side experience.  I am wondering what my best option would be for the following situation.  There is an API I want to get data from, but there is a limit to how many times I access that data per second, something like less than 10 requests per minute or so, before it gets frozen.  What can I use as a server to schedule a request to the API for all the information I need, every hour or so, so that I can then access the data from my server as many times as I want to from my mobile app?

Are there tools out there that I can take advantage of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, I recently had to learn a bit on the server side for the push notifications i'm trying to implement in a market data (fx) app i'm writing.

The best solution i've found is:

Assuming you're on a Mac,

1. Get MAMP [here](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) - it's PHP, MySQL and Apache webserver.

   - best bit about MAMP is it's a self contained app, so it won't mess with your OS X install
2. You can write PHP code to pull the data from the API, store it on your MySQL database you    set up with MAMP.
3. You can then write a little objective C code, to hit up your Apache webserver on another PHP file that pulls the data you stored earlier.

That's basically it, now I know what you're thinking, you probably don't know any PHP. Either did I until last weekend and you should see what I'm able to do in it now!

I only knew objective C, but even so learning PHP was very easy - and i'm not the best coder out there.

I have a PHP script that (within about 10 lines of code) goes to a website's API pulls JSON values for FX prices and stores them in my DB. I can then hit up my Webserver and pull the values.

Learning all of this has made me realise that Web applications are incredibly powerful, where before I never considered them when developing iOS apps.

Answer (score -2):

if you want to call your webservice after some time interval continuously then i guess NSTimer is the thing that helps you i have a bit of code that might help you for calling your method of parsing

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer
         scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
         target:self
         selector:@selector(methodOfParsing)
         userInfo:nil
         repeats:YES];
}
```

it will be called after every 2 second so you can manage this by replacing 2.0 by your desired value